# How to aggregate count records in a table with a folder-like heirarchy

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables.

PROF TBL:

```
------------------------------------
| pf_id | pf_parent_id | pf_foobar |
------------------------------------
|  1    | NULL         | lipsum    | -> root       -> count(2) aggregate(5)
|  2    | NULL         | lipsum    | -> root
|  3    | 1            | lipsum    | -> descendant
|  4    | 1            | lipsum    | -> descendant -> count(0) aggregate(3)
|  5    | 4            |           | -> descendant -> count(1) aggregate(3)
|  6    | 5            |           | -> leaf       -> count(2) since leaf(2)
------------------------------------
```

USER TBL:

```
---------------------------------------
| user_id | pf_id (ref) | user_foobar |
---------------------------------------
|   1     |  1          |  qwe        |
|   2     |  1          |             |
|   3     |  5          |             |
|   4     |  6          |             |
|   5     |  6          |  qwe        |
---------------------------------------
```

I intend to `COUNT()` every instance of the `pf_id` found in `usertbl` I get that fine for every distinct pf_id with this query.

```
SELECT proftbl.pf_id, proftbl.pf_parent_id, proftbl.pf_title,   COUNT(proftbl.pf_id),
FROM `proftbl`
LEFT JOIN `usertbl` ON `usertbl`.pf_id=`proftbl`.pf_id
GROUP BY `proftbl`.pf_id;
```

BUT I'd like to to aggregate the count of `pf_id` Records having descendants.
I don't know how to go about this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I like to write queries this way; I think it makes it more obvious where errors occur...

```
     SELECT proftbl.pf_id
          , proftbl.pf_parent_id
          , proftbl.pf_title
          , COUNT(proftbl.pf_id)
          , -- !!!!!!!!!!  SURELY SOME MISTAKE HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!
       FROM `proftbl`
       LEFT 
       JOIN `usertbl` 
         ON `usertbl`.pf_id = `proftbl`.pf_id
      GROUP 
         BY `proftbl`.pf_id;
```

Comment: yes, thanks. but, i'm not encountering any errors. I'm after the summation of descendant counts of all records. Any ideas? seems really complicated for me.

Comment: In that case, that's not really your query

Comment: yes. that's why i'm asking how. a colleague mentioned `select` inside `join`s... can't wrap around my head around that idea. hmmm

Comment: My point is that your claim that you "get that fine for every distinct pf_id with this query" is simply false, which, though it may not matter to you, leaves me perplexed.

Comment: yes it does. but after getting the distinct counts, I intend to sum up those that are descendant of some parent. What am i missing?